# How to add 1 second to the current date in automation script in Maximo

Tags: python, maximo

How can I add 1 second to the current date in Python. I'm able to fetch the current Date and second separately however I'm not sure how to add 1 second to it.

```
currentDate = MXServer.getMXServer().getDate()
 currentSecond = currentDate.getSeconds()
 newSecond = currentSecond - 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a Calendar. For example..

```py
from java.util import GregorianCalendar
from psdi.server import MXServer

currentDate = MXServer.getMXServer().getDate()
cal = GregorianCalendar()
cal.setTime(currentDate)
cal.add(cal.SECOND, 1)
print "currentDate: %s\nplusSecond: %s" % (currentDate.toString(), cal.getTime().toString())
```

Comment: There is also `currentDate.setTime(currentDate.getTime() + 1000)`. There are also the newer time objects in Java 8, like `Instant`, that can do these things too (and are probably preferred now over both Date and Calendar).

Comment: Adding 1000 was a nice, short trick. I have worked with `Instant` classes and methods before, but you keep having to convert back to `Date` for Maximo's sake. For a case like this, I'm not sure the juice (modernization) is worth the squeeze (code). But the squeeze might be about equal compared to a `Calendar`.